# Replacing empty lines with characters when reading csv using Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I have a csv with some empty lines on it and they get deleted after it is loaded. However, I do need those empty lines. Is there any way to replace those empty lines with a value, e.g. 0, when loading the csv file?

This is how I read my data:

```
val mycsv = sparksession.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .load("mycsvfile.csv")
```

Comment: This just caused me major problems as well and is a bug in spark that only happens when tabs (or probably other "only whitespace" characters are used as separator)

Comment: I just created an issue in the spark bug tracker for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-46876

Answer (score 0):

There is a "nullValue" option that allows you to specify the string that you want to use for null. You have to add this option whenever your read the file.

```
option("nullValue", ["0"])
```

Comment: this doesn't work as option takes 2 strings as its input parameter